# Regex matches on single words only

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I got the following function, which contains a regex

```
public function searchDOM( $content, $search, $replace, $excludedParents = [] )
{

$dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html(
$content,
true,
true,
DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET,
false,
DEFAULT_BR_TEXT,
DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT
);


foreach ( $dom->find( 'text' ) as $element ) {

if ( !in_array( $element->parent()->tag, $excludedParents ) )
$element->innertext = preg_replace(
'/\b' . preg_quote( $search, "/" ) . '\b/i',
$replace,
$element->innertext
);

}
```

I am passing `$search` to the function as follows:

```
    foreach ( $searcharray as $search ) {

        $text    = $search[ 'text' ];
        $url     = $search[ 'url' ];

        $replace = "<a href='$url'>\$0</a>";
        $content = $this->searchDOM(
            $content,
            $text,
            $replace,
            [ 'a', 'img', 'script', 'style', 'code', 'pre' ]
        );
    }
```

which works fine. But if the search string contains a `+` e.g. the detection fails.

How could I fix that?

Comment: I think you should post the whole relevant code. There is no problem with `/\bhello world\b/i`. I suspect you have an array of `$search`es. Is there a loop?

Comment: Works just fine as far as I can see. https://regex101.com/r/SAhfDf/1

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Ok, I still think the issue is how you pass `$search` into this function (and you have not shown that). First, pass `hello world`, then `hello`, then `world` - first handle the longest search phrases.

Comment: Please show how you pass `$search` to this function and `$search` value.

Comment: Alright, I got it working by changing the way I pass things to this function. But now I got a last little problem: If there are special chars like `+` in the search string, the detection fails. I will update my question.

Comment: Yeah, you need to sort `$searcharray` by the `'text'` dimension by length in descending order. As for `+`, it should work since you have it covered with `preg_quote`. Else, please provide an example when it fails.

Comment: It fails when `+` is at the beginning or end, right?

Comment: That's right...

Comment: See my answer below. Also, check  https://ideone.com/PGaHLh demo. Please let know if it is working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your search phrases may contain non-word characters, you should consider passing them to your function beginning with the longest one, in the descending order. First, pass `hello world`, then `hello`, then `world`, etc.

Now, if you have a non-word char at the start or end  of the search phrase, `/\b\+search\b/i` won't match `+search` in `I want +search.` because there is no word boundary between a space and a `+` (as both are non-word chars). However, it will find a match in `I want+search` as there is a word boundary between `t` and `+`.

Use lookarounds to assert the position that is not preceded/followed with a word char instead:

```
'/(?<!\w)' . preg_quote( $search, "/" ) . '(?!\w)/i'
```

There can arise another issue though: what you already replaced can be replaced again. To avoid that, build a dynamic regex from the `text` items, prep an array with texts-urls, and use a `preg_replace_callback`

This is a sample demo, and the findal code may differ depending on your input (I did not wrap it into a function,you can easily do it on your end):

```
$searches= array();
$searches = array(
        array("text" => "hello", "url" => "hello-URL"),
        array("text" => "world", "url" => "world-URL"), 
        array("text" => "hello world", "url" => "helloworld-URL") 
    );
usort($searches, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b['text']) - strlen($a['text']);
});
$pat = '~(?<!\w)(?:' . implode("|", 
        array_map(function($x) { return preg_quote($x['text'], '~'); }, $searches)
    ) . ')(?!\w)~i';
// echo "$pat\n"; // => ~(?<!\w)(?:hello world|hello|world)(?!\w)~i
$keys = array();
$vals = array();
foreach($searches as $search) {
    $keys[] = $search['text'];
    $vals[] = $search['url'];
}
$tmparr = array_combine($keys, $vals);

$text = preg_replace_callback($pat, function($m) use ($tmparr) {
    return "<a href='" . $tmparr[$m[0]] . "'>" . $m[0] . "</a>"; }, $text);

echo $text;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/id7pG).